# Specific URL calling

Tags: django

when I call any of URL from urls.py so only the top one URL's result is returned. like I call the second URL name = 'test' or name = 'detail', it will return only the first URL name = 'list', not which I want.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name = 'list'),
url(r'',views.TestView.as_view(), name  = 'test'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail'),
```

]

Comment: right now you basically have 3 url pattern the same( in this case it's `/`) so it will get the first one that it match, you need to make the other 2 patterns different

Comment: Django starts to match the URLs from top to bottom and so you did not specify any URL pattern and Django always matches the first one.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have 3 of the same pattern of url, you need to change the pattern so it specific which view to call:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name = 'list'),
  url(r'^/test$',views.TestView.as_view(), name  = 'test'),
  url(r'^/detail/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail'),
]
```

But i don't recommend to use url() because it's gonna be deprecated soon [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#url):

> url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None) This function is an alias to
>   django.urls.re_path(). It’s likely to be deprecated in a future
>   release.

Comment: I think, in this case Django always matches the first one. because the first pattern contains all patterns that you specified after that

Comment: I think you should rearrange them

Comment: Add `r'^&'` for first url and it will match only empty url.

Comment: No, the terminator character is `$` not `%`.

Comment: thank for the suggestion thou, i haven't use url()(mostly path) in a long time so forgot about it's regex

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^list/$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name = 'list'),
url(r'',views.TestView.as_view(), name  = 'test'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail'),
]

actually it takes one blank or slash in URL at a time.
when someone hits a URL it goes again to the first 
slash or blank value when it has any other value except 
slash it will go to it.
```